# Why is `download.file()` downloading a corrupted file from a working public Dropbox link?

Tags: r, download, dropbox, readxl

Edit: So I've managed to get something else to work (included below). But I would still like to understand why my first attempt was unsuccessful.

This is me trying to use download.file to download my publicly available Dropbox file:

```r
library("readxl")

# Define public download link location ------------------------------------------
excelUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9lm9y7nso8yw1x/dashboardTotals.xlsx?dl=1"
     # I've experimented with appending '&raw=1' to this, doesn't seem to do anything.

# Function for downloading .xlsx into current wd --------------------------------
read_url_excel <- function(url,saveas = paste0(getwd(),"/newExcelFile.xlsx")){
  download.file(url, destfile = saveas)
  url_excel <- readxl::read_excel(saveas)
  return(url_excel)
}

# This doesn't work, because the file is corrupted and can't be read by read_excel()
excelTable = read_url_excel(excelUrl)
#> Error: Evaluation error: error reading from the connection.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can probably tell I'm not really sure how connections / files work in R. I've managed to get this to work instead:

```r
excelUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9lm9y7nso8yw1x/dashboardTotals.xlsx?dl=1&raw=1"

tmpF <- paste0(getwd(),"/newTing.xlsx")
theFile <- url(excelUrl, open="rb")

binary = readBin(theFile,raw(),100000)

writeBin(binary,tmpF)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How come method 1 fails and method 2 succeeds?

Comment: Your first method executes fine on ubuntu (setting `saveas = temp<-tempfile()`). What is your OS? Maybe try adding `mode="wb"` to download file?

Comment: @user20650 running on Windows 10. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: did adding `mode="wb"` solve it ? -- I suggested this as xlsx are compressed files and `download.file` has different behaviours across operating systems